# Login form requires second click to submit

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My backend login form submits with a single click of the login button. It creates an `<input type="hidden" name="login-button">` element then shortly thereafter submits. On the frontend the same is created on click but never posts the data until I click the button again.

Here is a sample of the view code:

```
<div id="login-form" class="col-sm-12">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-4 forgotPassword">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox() ?>
            <div style="margin:auto;color:#fff;margin:1em 0;font-size:10px;">
                if you forgot your password you can <?= Html::a('reset it', ['site/request-password-reset']) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary loginButton', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
```

The only difference I am seeing between the two is that there are some additional `<div>` tags that have been added for styling purposes. I have even removed those and I am still seeing the same issues.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `id` on the form `div` was causing the issue. Removing this has cleared everything up.

It was causing a conflict because it had the same `id` as the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that usually you assign model "formName" as your form id

```php
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName()]); ?>
```